# New admin submenu using other baseurl

Tags: magento2, admin, menu

I've used the official `devdoc` site tutorial, for doing my own submenu page in the M2 backend.

Everything is working, I see the menu slot, I can open it and have a HelloWorld showing.
But the baseUrl is changing, so every M2 js and CSS file is not loading?

On every M2 admin page the url is:

static/version1648803400/adminhtml **/Magento/backend/** en_US/requirejs/require.js

On my new subpage/menu:

static/version1648803400/adminhtml **/_view/** en_US/requirejs/require.js

What am I missing?